# Firestore composite Indexing not working: The query requires an index

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
UserCollection/{id}/PlayerCollection/{id}
```

In the last document, there are number of fields

```
active: true or false 
dateInMillies : 123456789




return _firestore
        .collection('UserCollection')
        .document(userID)
        .collection("PlayerCollection")
        .orderBy('dateInMillis', descending: true)
        .where('active', isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots();
```

this block of code through an exception:

```
failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: link to fix it
```

but the link is broken, so i must do it manually!

so, i went to indexes tab, and created a new composite index

```
collectionID : PlayerCollection
Fields Indexed: dateInMillis : Descending , active : Ascending
```

but also didn`t work!

Comment: You should consider contacting Firebase support about the broken link.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved D:

I contacted Firebase support about the broken URL and here is the solution:

> It seems that you might have another account linked on your browser.
>   Probably gmail, if that is the case, please verify that your current
>   session corresponds with the selected project, or simply try logout /
>   login with the account that owns the project. You can also try it from
>   an incognito window

And the generated link solved my issue.

Answer (score 6):

I have an alternative answer.

Make sure when you open the link that you don't include any random characters at the end. I opened the link from vscode's terminal, and it actually had three links that were available to open, but two of them had a trailing comma, which opened a white screen in the Firebase console.

Comment: For me VS code was adding a `]` so change: "...IX19uYW1lX18QAg]" to "...IX19uYW1lX18QAg"

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

I found that the fields indexed should be exactly the same in the query, no more, no less.

If you want to make a new query with different fields (but still in the same collection), you can create new composite indexing with the same collection name.

I hope this will solve the problem.